# Structuring select statement from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables that I am using to try and get the customer orders they are:

```
account
- account_id
- username

product
- product_number
- product_name

customer_order
- customer_order_id
- fk_account_id (foreign key)

customer_order_details
- fk_customer_order_id (foreign key)
- fk_product_id (foreign key)
```

This is my query... it's a bit confusing but:

```sql
SELECT customer_order_details.fk_customer_order_id, product.product_name,
customer_order_details.colour, customer_order_details.size
FROM customer_order, customer_order_details, product, account
WHERE customer_order.customer_order_id = 
customer_order_details.fk_customer_order_id
AND customer_order_details.fk_product_id = product.product_id
AND customer_order.fk_account_id = account.account_id
AND account.username = 'user1'
GROUP BY customer_order_details.fk_customer_order_id;
```

It should group by the foreign key (fk_customer_order_id) in the customer_order_details table. The results that I want are like this:

```
1
Microfleece Vest
Jacket With Hood

2
Jacket With Hood
```

Instead I get something like:

```
1
Microfleece Vest

2
Jacket With Hood
```

My PHP code is simply running through a while loop and printing out the product_name and fk_customer_order_id.

Comment: I thought the WHERE statement is joining them? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Records in the database show that there should be 2 products on order 1 it's only giving me the one.

Comment: @jtheman `JOIN`s can be implicitly written using the syntax @Dan used, but the optimizer assumes an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of JOIN syntax:

```sql
 SELECT d.fk_customer_order_id, p.product_name, d.colour, d.size
 FROM customer_order AS o
 LEFT JOIN customer_order_details AS d ON o.customer_order_id = d.fk_customer_order_id
 LEFT JOIN product AS p ON d.fk_product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT JOIN account as a ON o.fk_account_id = a.account_id
 WHERE a.username = 'user1'
 GROUP BY d.fk_customer_order_id
 ORDER BY d.fk_customer_order_id;
```

Try the above instead. I made it a little easier to read with table aliases. To speed up the query, make sure you have indexes set for all relationship keys.

However your output will be:

```
1 Microfleece Vest
1 Jacket With Hood
2 Jacket With Hood
```

Since grouping on order details will list one row per detail...